# Broadcast client message to all clients in a chatroom Java

Tags: java, sockets, for-loop, arraylist, server

So I've been making a chatroom based off a single server, where clients can connect and talk in the chatroom. At the moment each client can speak to the server and the server returns what the client has said. But I've been struggling to broadcast a single client message to all clients.

I stored all socket connections in an **ArrayList** and then created a for loop to iterate through all the connections to echo a single message to all the connected clients. Unfortunately my code is not working and I can't understand why. Here's my code:

**Handler code:**

```
public class Handler implements Runnable {

private Socket client;
String message = "";

public Handler(Socket client){
    this.client = client;
}

@Override
public void run() {
  try{  
    try{
        ChatClient CCG = new ChatClient();
        Scanner INPUT = new Scanner(client.getInputStream()); //input data from the server
        PrintWriter OUT = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());  //output data from the server
        while(true){

            if(!INPUT.hasNextLine()){   //if nothings there, end it
                    return;
            }

            message = INPUT.nextLine(); //get input

            System.out.println("Client HANDLER said: "+ message);

                //echo out what the client says to all the users
            for(int i=1; i<= ChatServer.ConnectionArray.size(); i++){

                Socket TEMP_SOCK = (Socket) ChatServer.ConnectionArray.get(i-1);
                PrintWriter TEMP_OUT = new PrintWriter(TEMP_SOCK.getOutputStream());
                TEMP_OUT.println(message);
                TEMP_OUT.flush();
                System.out.println("Sent to: " + TEMP_SOCK.getLocalAddress().getHostName());    //displyed in the console
            }
        }

    }finally{
            client.close();
        }
    }catch(Exception X){
        X.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

**EDIT:** Changed **client.getOutputStream()** to **TEMP_SOCK.getOutputStream()** but still no luck :/

**Server code:**

```
public class ChatServer {

public static ServerSocket server;
public static boolean ServerOn=true; 
public static ArrayList<Socket> ConnectionArray = new ArrayList<Socket>();  //holds all the connections so messages can be echoed to all the other users
public static ArrayList<String> CurrentUsers = new ArrayList<String>(); //current users

public static void main(String[] args){
    //ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);    //number of clients allowed to join the server
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(14001);
        System.out.println("Server started!");
        System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");

        while(true){

            try {
                //ChatClient chatClient = new ChatClient();
                Socket client = server.accept();
                ConnectionArray.add(client);  //add socket to connection array and allows multiple users to enter server
                System.out.println(ConnectionArray);
                //CurrentUsers.add(chatClient.user);
                //System.out.println("Current users: "+CurrentUsers);
                System.out.println("Client connected from: " + client.getLocalAddress().getHostName());   //gets their ip address and local host name
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Handler(client));
                thread.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**Client Code:**

```
public class ChatClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Socket sock;
String message;
int port = 14001;
PrintWriter write;
BufferedReader read;
String user;
ArrayList<String> usersOnline = new ArrayList();
InputStreamReader streamreader;
boolean userConnected = false;

public ChatClient() {
    initComponents();
}

/*public class Incoming implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        try{
            sock = new Socket("localhost",14001);
            write = new PrintWriter(out);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}*/

public void addUser(){
    onlineUsersTextArea.append(user+" \n");
    usersOnline.add(user);
    System.out.println(usersOnline);
}

/*public void Send(){
    String bye = (user + ": :Disconnect");
    try{
        write.println(bye);
        write.flush();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        chatTextArea.append("Could not send disconnect message. \n");
    }
}*/

public void userDisconnected(){
    chatTextArea.append(user + " has disconnected.\n");
}

public void Disconnect(){
    try{
        chatTextArea.append("Disconnected.\n"); // Notify user that they have disconnected
        write.flush();
        sock.close();   // Closes the socket
        System.out.println(user + " has disconnected.");
    }catch(Exception e){
        chatTextArea.append("Failure to disconnect.\n");
    }

    userConnected = false;
    onlineUsersTextArea.setText("");    // Remove name from online users
    usernameInputField.setEditable(true);   // Allows a username to be created
}

private void connectButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    if(userConnected == false){
        user = usernameInputField.getText();
        usernameInputField.setEditable(false);

    try{
        sock = new Socket("localhost", port);
        InputStreamReader sReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        write = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        read = new BufferedReader(sReader);
        addUser();
        chatTextArea.append(user + " has connected. \n");
        write.println(user+" has connected.");  // Display username of client when connection is established
        write.flush();  // Flushes the stream
        userConnected = true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        chatTextArea.append("Failed to connect.\n");
        usernameInputField.setEditable(true);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }else if(userConnected == true){
        chatTextArea.append("You are already connected. \n");
    }
}                                             

private void disconnectButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    Disconnect();
    userDisconnected();
}                                                

private void sendButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    String nothing = "";
    if((userInputTextArea.getText()).equals(nothing)){
        userInputTextArea.setText("");
        userInputTextArea.requestFocus();
    }else{
        try{
            chatTextArea.append(user + ": " + userInputTextArea.getText()+" \n");
            write.println(user + ": " + userInputTextArea.getText());
            write.flush();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            chatTextArea.append("Message failed to send. \n");
        }
        userInputTextArea.setText("");
        userInputTextArea.requestFocus();
    }

    userInputTextArea.setText("");
    userInputTextArea.requestFocus();
}                                          

private void usernameInputFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
}                                                  

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ChatClient().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

My **for loop** is in the **Handler** class. I'm not understanding why the message isn't being sent out to the clients. The **TEMP_SOCK** (temporary socket) should work (I think) but the server only receives the messages but doesn't echo them.

Any help on how to go about this would be really appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: @YogeshBadke different JVMs I think. I first run the ChatServer class and then the ChatClient class separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PrintWriter TEMP_OUT = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());` means you're always sending to the same client, you should use `PrintWriter TEMP_OUT = new PrintWriter(TEMP_SOCK.getOutputStream());`

Comment: Just tried that with 2 connected clients and no messages show up on either consoles :/

Comment: Are you sure the client code is not to blame? Can you maybe post some of that as well?

Comment: Just edited the post. Please excuse the large amount of code bc I've implemented a GUI so i wasn't sure on what methods would be helpful. I haven't shown the actual GUI code for obvious reasons :)

Comment: I don't see where you're reading the message from the server. You'd need something like `inputLine = read.readLine()`

Comment: Where would I place that code in my client class? Apologies for my lack of knowledge. Would I place it in the public ChatClient where the initComponents() method is?

Comment: Without trying to be rude: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html